# Is @ngrx/store createSelector() really necessary?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects, ngrx-store-4.0

I really like the clean API of `this.store.select('media', 'games');`

I don't need to create any selectors with `createSelector()`, and don't need to import anything. I feel selectors become this great big middle layer when the project gets big. `media.selectors.ts` becomes a monolithic file.

I end up having a lot of selectors doing simple things, so instead of:

```
this.store.select('media', 'games');
```

I do:

```
import * as fromMedia '../media'

this.store.select(fromMedia.getAllGamesSelector());
```

And ditto for `movies` for example:

```
import * as fromMedia '../media'

this.store.select(fromMedia.getAllMoviesSelector());
```

I understand `createSelector()` has benefits of memoization, but I highly doubt doing simple selection with `strings` is THAT much slower...

Every guide I have read requires you to must use `createSelector()`

So my question is, when is it appropriate to use `createSelector()`? Is it ok to use the string selector, or is it frowned upon and is bad practice?

Comment: Also type safety, if you are wondering why it provides type safety, try and see

Comment: `@ngrx/store` string selectors comes with type checking. If you make a typo, VSCode will alert you, and underline in red.

Answer (score 5):

the concept of `selector` is really useful not only for memoization purposes, and while it can seem to add unnecessary scaffolding, it becomes very important for big projects:

1. **Make refactoring very easy**: Immagine you need to change your state structure and you don't have selectors, then you'll probably end up refactoring all of your project, view components included.
2. **Allow `derived data` extraction**, you can keep your store clean and neat, holding only important data and leave derivation to selectors (imagine you want to display the total amount of your cart, so you can create a selector which collects all the products in your cart and sums their prices).

Answer (score 2):

`memoization` is not the only benefit that `createSelector()` can bring you.
Imagine to have a complex and nested data structure. You would have to traverse your data to find the properties you need. 
With `selectors` you can easily reference various pieces of your data structure, combine them, merge them and than ship them to your components for consumption.

In conslusion, if you have a complex data structure to handle, they are really necessary.

Comment: So would you say for simple data structures, using `string` select is ok? Or is it best to just use `createSelector()` all the way? If the data structure is that complex, perhaps there is a flaw in the data design though.

Comment: I would use `createSelector()` just for best practice, but you can definitely skip it for simpler data structures. BTW, complex data stucture doesn't always mean there's a flaw in data design, sometimes things really need to be aggrgated into a single model, maybe to avoid to dispatching many queries to DB to get your data, but that also depends on the DB you're using. In the end, you should evaluate your specific situation and then adapt your solution to it.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can pass in a fat arrow function to store.select.  So instead of this:

> this.store.select('media', 'games');

do this:

> this.store.select(state => state.media.games);

If you want to skip the whole createSelector stuff you might end up doing a lot of combineLatest and withLatestFrom in your components in order to combine different parts of state.  If you use a lot of those rxjs operators it might be a better fit to introduce the createSelector() layer.

Comment: Agreed. I am seeing more and more of the benefits of createSelector()